# Cómo modificar el modal de bootstrap 5? Quiero que sea un pop up transparente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Soy algo nuevo usando bootstrap, la configuración por defecto hace que tenga un fondo blanco con un banear superior con título.

¿Que quiero hacer?
Necesito que al dar click a un botón de “Más información” salga un pop up transparente que tenga una X en la esquina superior derecha para cerrar el popup, lo que contendrá el popup es una imagen, estoy usando bootstrap para asegurarme que se vea correcto en cualquier dispositivo.

Actualmente el popup muestra la imagen pero tiene todo un fondo blanco del modal que me roba mucho espacio y todo ese espacio no lo necesito solo ocupo que abra la imagen y que detrás quede la página de fondo con cierta transparencia.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], este no es un sitio para solicitar que alguien realice un proyecto o tarea, te recomiendo leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para que te familiarices con las normas del sitio. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código que has utilizado hasta ahora y los errores que te impiden lograr lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre puedes sobreescribir propiedades del css. Por ejemplo puedes crear una clase `CustomModal` y hacer lo siguiente:

```css
img{
 width:200px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.CustomModal .modal-dialog{
   max-width: fit-content !important;
   pointer-events: auto;
   background-color:transparent;
}

.CustomModal .btn-close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#MiModal">
    Abrir
</button>

<div class="modal fade CustomModal" id="MiModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    <img >
  </div>
</div>
```

La ventana modal de bootstrap se compone de varias partes:

- modal-dialog

  - modal-content

    - modal-header
    - modal-body
    - modal-footer

Los cuales son `div` que van dando formato de ventana, principalmente agregando `margin` y `padding`, como no nos interesa eso, solo vamos a ocupamos `modal-dialog`, donde le cambiamos el width para que se ajuste a la imagen, le seteamos el `pointer-event` en auto ya que bootstrap lo cambia (sin esto el botón cerrar no funciona)

Además dentro agregamos un botón para cerrar, y su respectivo css con position:absolute para sacarlo fuera de la imagen como tu quieres.

Comment: Excelente solución, literalmente fuiste 100% al punto que necesitaba, ¡Excelente! Muchas gracias por contribuir a mi aprendizaje! 
Ojalá le sirva a alguien más.

Comment: Por cierto, conoces como editar el carousel? 

El que tiene bootstrap tiene incluidas las flechas dentro de la imagen pero no soy muy fan ya que se pierde con la imagen, quisiera tener las flechas fuera del recuadro de la imagen, estuve jugando con CSS pero solo logro mover las flechas dentro del recuadro que incluye las imagenes.

Comment: @Junkboy Me alegro haber podido ayudarte. Sobre tu otra pregunta, creo que se puede hacer, pero debes generar una nueva pregunta, te recomiendo colocar código de lo has intentado, ya que es común cerrar o votar negativamente a preguntas que no lo incluyen (en esta te salvaste por el horario).

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Yussef por tus comentarios, soy nuevo en stackoverflow, así que todo ayuda, ya he creado una nueva pregunta esta vez incluyendo codigo e imagenes para facilitarlo. Por si tienes tiempo y gustas darte una vuelta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580311/personalizar-carousel-bootstrap-5-sacar-flechas-de-la-imagen-a%c3%b1adir-previsua